# how to use PHP to convert numerical string to float?

Tags: php

I got a string

```
    "1.0E+7"
```

And i hope convert it to a float

```
    10000000.00
```

Is there any php functions do this job? Or I should do this conversion myself?

Further more, I will receive many strings like this, some are numerical and some are in scientific format, how can I convert all of them correctly without knowing the content?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? PHP understands scientific notation, so it will treat these as floats when you use them in mathmatical expressions.

Comment: I need to check if the float have less than 3 digital number, I write a function myself(expload the number by "."), however when it meets mathmatical expression, it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not just `if ($number < 1000)`?

Comment: sorry, i misspelled it....I mean at most 3 decimal digit.

Comment: You mean 3 digits AFTER the decimal point?

Comment: It's sad I was working on my answer. :^ (

Comment: @Barmar yes.............

Comment: Use `$number - floor($number)` to get the fractional part of the number.

Comment: @sectus well, your answer is great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [floatval()](http://www.php.net/floatval):

```
$num = "1.0E+7";
$fl = floatval ($num);

printf ("%.02f", $fl);
// Result: 10000000.00
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [`floatval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

```
<?php
echo floatval("1.0E+7").".00";//10000000.00
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this example for converting your string var into float type:

```
<?php
$var = '122.34343The';
$float_value_of_var = floatval($var);
echo $float_value_of_var; // 122.34343
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to cast it....

```
$val ="1.0E+7"
(float) $val
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
// type casting
var_dump((float) "1.0E+7");   // float(10000000)
// type juggling
var_dump("1.0E+7" + 0.0);     // float(10000000)
// function 
var_dump(floatval("1.0E+7")); // float(10000000)

// other stuff
var_dump(round("1.0E+7"));    // float(10000000)
var_dump(floor("1.0E+7"));    // float(10000000)
var_dump(ceil("1.0E+7"));     // float(10000000)
var_dump(abs("1.0E+7"));      // float(10000000) 

// weird
var_dump(unserialize("d:"."1.0E+7".";")); // float(10000000) 
var_dump(json_decode('1.0E+7')); // float(10000000)
```

And read [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), [string conversion to numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion), [floatval](http://php.net/floatval)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$var = '1.0E+7';
$float_value_of_var = floatval($var);
printf ("%.02f", $float_value_of_var);
// 10000000.00
?>
```